# Error with jQuery-te-1.4.0, linkinput.is("[value^=http://]"))

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been using jQuery TE for a while now with no issues until v1.4.0.   When I click on the add link button in the toolbar, the script generates an error on line 735 in the file jquery-te-1.4.0.js, which I show below.  I assumed that perhaps the caret had something to do with it, but that's not the case because after I remove the caret, it still generates an error on that line

```
if(currentType!="1" && !linkinput.is("[value^=http://]"))
```

I didn't post the entire file here because it's rather large, just wondering why the error so I can edit it out.  'll revert to an earlier version to see if that doesn't fix the issue, but I'm curious as to what's going on here.

******* UPDATE *******

I'm using jQuery v3.7.1, the error message is:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [value^=http://]
    at I.error (jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2:11769)
    at Y (jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2:17234)
    at ne (jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2:19293)
    at re (jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2:20522)
    at I (jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2:7520)
    at I.matchesSelector (jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2:11454)
    at ce.filter (jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2:21675)
    at T (jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2:21559)
    at ce.fn.init.is (jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2:22177)
    at linkInputSet (jquery-te-1.4.0.js:735:44)
```

I just assumed that the issue was with jQuery-te, it may not be.  I'm stepping through the code in jQuery-3-7-1 and the error occurs on this line:

```
return !!T(this, "string" == typeof e && b.test(e) ? ce(e) : e || [], !1).length
```

The string is passed to the function properly, just generates the error.

That line of code is in the following function:

```
is: function(e) {
  return !!T(this, "string" == typeof e && b.test(e) ? ce(e) : e || [], !1).length
}
```

I tried jQuery v3.6.4, same error.

Comment: You could try `.is("[value^='http://']")` (assuming this is your code).  Otherwise, please specify the version of jquery you are using

Comment: What's the specific error you get?  When I tried it there were no error.

Comment: Same question.  What's the error?

Comment: @fdomn-m I tried your suggestion, I changed that line of code in the jQuery-te-1-4-0.js file from `[value^=http://]` to `[value^='http://']` and the error disappeared and the textbox displayed the correct link.  I'll report the issue back to the jQuery-TE folks and perhaps they can provide a fix or at least a reason why I get the error.  maybe it's my page, I have no idea.